# 100% height on Bootstrap 4 columns (no scrollbar on browser)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and trying to set 3 columns on the page to have 100% height - to only have scrollbars on the columns and NOT on the page. I have tried h-100 on the **row** div as well as various custom css changes like setting the height and max-height to 100% on each of the columns and other solutions I found on Stack Overflow and other sites. No matter what I do, I just cannot get it working right. Would be grateful if somebody could help me out. Here is the site:

https://gordon-matt.github.io/Extenso/

To see what I am trying to do, go here:
https://gordon-matt.github.io/Extenso/#assembly/bde7b8d9-116a-4e39-939f-2acce6aba664

then click the first button on the left (the one that says "18 Classes"). You will see the middle column is a list group and will fill with items. The scrollbars will appear, but they extend longer than the page itself and now there's a scrollbar on the browser.. Instead, I don't want any scrollbars on the browser and ONLY a scrollbar on the columns. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to not to use `!important` too often, it makes specificity unpredictable,

Here is my solution, just check following CSS IDs and classes:

```
#types {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    height: 58vh;
}

.h-100 {
    height: 73vh !important;
}
```

Please let me know if it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Property
`style="height:100vh"`

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried adding that to various different elements now and it doesn't work.

Comment: Also note that `height: 100vh` on mobile doesn't account for the address bar (at least in Chrome on Android/Pixel)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `height: 100vh;` style for your section that you want to be 100% height for every device.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried adding that to various different elements now and it doesn't work.